# How can I view detailed information on a WiFi connection on an Android device?

Tags: wi-fi, networking

**Background / Purpose**
I'm setting up a wireless network in which a Raspberry Pi works as the router & access point (following [Adafruit's Guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point?view=all)). After getting it all set up, I tested the network by connecting my Samsung S6 to the new wireless network (having disabled mobile data, of course), and successfully accessed the internet (and double-checked by watching the RasPi's syslog).

I'm having trouble connecting other devices to the network, and I think it may be due to settings or parameters I'm using but known nothing about (`pairwise` (TKIP?), `proto` (WPA2?), etc.).

I'm not asking about those settings & such, I know that's a question for a different forum -- rather, I want to know if it's possible to get detailed information from Android about the WiFi network it's connected to. Perhaps through the developer/debug mode, or using an external tool or application connected to or installed on the Android device?

Comment: Maybe this can give you what you need: `adb shell dumpsys wifi`. You need [tag:adb] setup.

Comment: Try Network sygnal Info Pro (SSID, BSSID, MSC, speed, strength, cypher, freq, channel, etc)

Comment: Network Sygnal Info certainly provides a good amount of detailed information, and without having to root the phone. Since I ended up solving my original problem a different way, I can't say whether this would have given me exactly what I needed, but it is what I was looking for, so I'll consider it solved. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

From most (all?) Android handsets you can dial `*#*#4636#*#*` which will display a wifi menu with lots of detailed information regarding the wireless status.

Comment: does not work on my Android 9 Samsung Galaxy S10

Comment: Just tested it on my razer phone running 9.0 and it worked fine

Comment: Just tested it on my Samsung A40 and it doesn't work, so it's somewhat manufacturer dependent. This is definitely samsung _removing a feature_ though so you should be able to assume that any android handset _should_ be able to access this menu.